# docker-compose cannot connect to mysql

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

After hours of trying different things I find googling, still can't connect to MySQL.

This is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  apache:
    build: .
    container_name: apache-dot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./www-data:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 80:80

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql-dot
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxxxxx
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin-dot
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxxxxx
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 8000:80

networks:
    default:

volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
```

Docker compose builds correctly no with no errors.

docker logs and docker inspect doesn't reveal anything wrong.
docker network inspect looks good also.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

**SOLVED**

I've had to add to the PHPMyAdmin service `PMA_HOST: mysql`.

```
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin-dot
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxxxxx
      PMA_HOST: mysql  <====
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 8000:80
```

Comment: What process is trying to connect to MySQL?  From another container, the same host, a different host?  With what command line and host name?  The SO documentation has some hints on [ask]; there are a lot of things that could go wrong (and a lot of existing SO answers!).

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it's obvious from docker-compose.yaml. There are three containers, running on the same network. Apache is running on 0.0.0.0:80, MySQL running on 0.0.0.0:3306 and phpmyadmin is running on 0.0.0.0:8000.

Comment: Right, but who's _connecting_ to the server?  How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Because I did `docker exec -it CONTAINER bash` into MySQL container and I was able to log into MySql, see my database and his tables and when I try to log in using PHPMyAdmin says on top of the login form _Cannot log in to the MySQL server_ and at the bottom _mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve_

Comment: What name is it trying to connect to?

Comment: Please add screenshot of your PHPMyAdmin screen. What are you entering for the 'server' field? Localhost? You're supposed to enter the name of the container of database ie `mysql`

Comment: Didn't tried your solution @Sathya but good to know. Thank you anyways.

Comment: I tried in my app use `mysql` (service name) in the server field and didn't work @Sathya. But you inspired me enough to use the container name `mysql-dot` instead in the server field and is working.
Anyways, you're right `localhost` is not working. Thanks again.